# javascript cloneNode() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clonenode, jquery-clone

I have in an html page a select element with an id="a" (for example).
I have a function called f().
when I write

```
$("#a").on("change",f);
```

it works, meaning every time I change the selected value in the drop down list the function f() is called.

I want to clone this select in another place in the page.
I have this code:

```
var oldSelect=$("#a")
var newSelect=oldSelect[0].cloneNode(true);
newSelect.id="b";
$("#b").on("change",f);
```

and when I change the selected value in the new dropdown list, the function f() isn't called.

I tried debugging it using the chrome's devTools and it apears that $("#a") is kind of an array length 1 that in the first place has the select itself. But $("#b") doesn't have the "0" property containing the select itself.

Does anyone know why does it happen? how can I clone a select element with all its options and callbacks?

Comment: could you try this one?
`var newSelect = $("#a").clone(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you cloned the existing `#a`, you haven't inserted it into the document yet in the code you've shown, so `$("#b")` will not give you any elements in return. Either insert it before selecting it with `$`, eg:

```
$(container).append(newSelect);
$("#b").on("change",f);
```

where `container` is the element you want to append the new `<select>` to.

Or add the listener directly to the element, instead of selecting it again:

```
var newSelect=oldSelect.clone(true);
newSelect
  .prop('id', 'b')
  .on("change",f)
  .appendTo(container);
```

(Note that in the above, `newSelect` is a jQuery collection, not an HTMLSelectElement.)

```js
const f = () => console.log('change');

var oldSelect = $("#a");
oldSelect.on("change",f);

var newSelect = oldSelect.clone(true);
newSelect
  .prop('id', 'b')
  .on("change", f)
  .appendTo('#container');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select id="a">
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what to do if I don't have an id for the container? it is a td (inside a table) that I want to put the select inside. the rows to the table are added dynamically so I don't want to give them an id

Comment: You don't need an ID, you just need some way to select the parent to append to. Any CSS selector which works will do, as will a reference to the `<td>` in an element or jQuery collection.

Comment: Thanks! the suggestion to move the on() after inserting it into the document works!!